# Can I get the charts in Dashboards of Customization session?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

[image]

I am going to export those dashboards into my web using google analytics api.

Does google analytics api have any methods to get the data of the dashboards?
Or I have to create one by one myself using google analytics api?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics API us used for extracting data from Google Analytics.  In the case of the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) its dimensions and metric data.   In the Case of the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) its information about the account itself.

Dashboards are UI data from the [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) website.  There is no way to export that information.

So no you are not going to be extracting dashboard info using any of the Google analytics APIs.